# Shouldn't run tor as root, can't run tor as non-root

Tags: configuration

Every time I try to run tor as non root I get the error

```
Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ cannot be read: Permission denied
```

So then when I run it as root it says

```
You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
```

I'm trying to get a tor website running on my pi. What should I do?

Edit: I fixed it. Apparently the /var/lib/tor folder is owned by a used "debian-tor". Run tor with `sudo -u debian-tor tor` to get it to work

Comment: How did you install tor, and what are the permissions on `/var/lib/tor` and `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service`? What’s the value of `HiddenServiceDir` in your torrc file? You need to make sure that the user running tor has permission to access this directory.

Comment: This led me to the solution. I just made the edit. Thanks!